# Python Pandas NLTK How to Apply Port Stemmer to Dataframe Column That has Been Tokenized Already

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, stemming

I have the following sample dataset:

```
No  category    problem_definition
175 2521        ['coffee', 'maker', 'brewing', 'properly', '420']
211 1438        ['galley', 'work', 'table', 'stuck']
912 2698        ['cloth', 'floor', 'coming', 'aft']
572 2521        ['compartment', 'door', 'stuck']
```

The problem_definition field has already gone through stop words removal and tokenizing.  Now I am trying to apply Port Stemmer to the problem_definition column.

I tried the following code:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()

df['problem_definition_stemmed'] = df['problem_definition_stopwords'].apply(lambda x : [PorterStemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'PorterStemmer' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

`PosrterStemmer` is a class constructor. It does not have method `.stem`. The actual stemmer is `ps`. `PorterStemmer.stem(y)` must be `ps.stem(y)`.